# Remove and add elements from same position in snap svg group

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I have snap svg group of 5 elements like;

```
let canvas = Snap('#svg');
let myGroup = canvas.g();

myGroup.add(canvas.rect(100, 200, 110, 220).attr({fill: '#000'}));
myGroup.add(canvas.circle(400, 400, 50).attr({fill: '#500'}));

// want to remove this element later
myGroup.add(canvas.rect(100, 200, 50, 60).attr({fill: '#050'}));

myGroup.add(canvas.text(50, 100, 'Some Text').attr({stroke: '#005'}));
myGroup.add(canvas.rect(700, 200, 110, 220).attr({fill: '#055'}));
```

Then I can access the specific elements of `myGroup` using the index, for instance, if I want to change the attributes of text I can use `myGroup[3]` because it is at 3rd index in `myGroup`.

Now I want to remove the element at 2nd index and then add some other element at same index, so I used `remove()` method like;

```
myGroup[2].remove();
myGroup.add(canvas.path('M 100 200 l 30 35').attr({stroke: '#050'}));
```

but the problem is; the elements at 3rd and 4th index got shifted up (2nd and 3rd respectively) and new element has been added to 4th index.

Does anyone know how can I add element at the same index?

Comment: In the DOM there is ``.replaceWith`` but I don't know how Snap will deal with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith

Comment: Snap.svg elements are throwing error saying ```myGroup[2].replaceWith```  is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `insertAfter` or `insertBefore` method to achieve this.

**Example:**

If you like replace a node from canvas group with an index of 2. remove the node using `remove` method.

```
myGroup[2].remove();
```

and insert the new node with `insertBefore` method

```
canvas.path('M 100 110 l 30 35').attr({
   stroke: '#050'
}).insertBefore(myGroup[2]);
```

this will replace the old node with the new one.

**Example Solution:**

```js
let canvas = Snap('#svg');

let myGroup = canvas.g();

myGroup.add(canvas.rect(100, 110, 110, 220).attr({
  fill: '#000'
}));
myGroup.add(canvas.circle(400, 400, 50).attr({
  fill: '#500'
}));

// want to remove this element later
myGroup.add(canvas.rect(100, 110, 50, 60).attr({
  fill: '#050'
}));

myGroup.add(canvas.text(50, 100, 'Some Text').attr({
  stroke: '#005'
}));
myGroup.add(canvas.rect(700, 200, 110, 220).attr({
  fill: '#055'
}));

function replaceElement() {
  myGroup[2].remove();
  canvas.path('M 100 110 l 30 35').attr({
    stroke: '#050'
  }).insertBefore(myGroup[2]);
}
```

```css
#svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js" integrity="sha512-Gk+uNk8NWN235mIkS6B7/424TsDuPDaoAsUekJCKTWLKP6wlaPv+PBGfO7dbvZeibVPGW+mYidz0vL0XaWwz4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button onclick="replaceElement()">replace</button>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: For my case it should be ```canvas.path('M 100 110 l 30 35').attr({stroke: '#050'
  }).insertAfter(myGroup[2]);``` Ref: ```http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.insertAfter```. Btw it solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @kapilsarwat Updated the solution